# Estimated R9 290 h/s?

Tags: mining-hardware

I'm looking to build a dedicated mining rig and found a cheap r9 290, but when I checked this website http://monerobechmarks.byethost5.com/index.php?i=1 that shows mining benchmarks, the ones for the 290 were all over the place. It ranged from 789h/s to 250 h/s. Any idea what I would actually be getting if mining with a r9 290?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have two R9 290's online mining. I have an AMD Sapphire running approximately 723h/s sure I can do it a little better. Also have a PowerColor running but its only at 636h/s hopefully that will give you a little idea. A lot depends on the model.